# How to access an asp.net control's info from a parent View/Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

As a background, I am coding in c# using MVC. I have a partial view (called CategorySelection) which simply displays a list of all Categories that it receives through its model.

```
@using MyProject.Models;
@model CategorySelectionModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <select id="CategoryNamesList" size="6">

        @if(Model.Categories.Count() == 0)
        {
            <option>No Categories defined.</option>
            <option>Please define a category first.</option>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Category c in Model.Categories)
            {
                if (c.Id == Model.SelectedCategoryId)
                {
                    <option selected="selected">@c.Name</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option>@c.Name</option>
                }
            }
        }
    </select>
}
```

I am then including this partial view inside a parent view which is called EditItems (each item has a category, which is displayed/selected through partial view)

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div>@Html.LabelFor(mode => Model.Category)</div>
                @Html.Partial("CategorySelection", new CategorySelectionModel { Categories = new dbContext().Categories, SelectedCategoryId = Model.Category.Id })
</div>
```

So far so good. The code selects the correct category from the list inside the partial view. However, the problem is that I dont know how to get the new value of the CategoryId (the item from CategoryNamesList that was clicked on) from the partialview when the user clicks on a new category (as the name suggests in the EditItem view, I want to know which category user has selected to update the categories accordingly).
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: When & where do you want to get the newly selected item from the dropdown ?

Comment: Do you mean get the value when you submit the form? (your `<select>` element does not even have a `name` attribute). I recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics of how to generate a view, in particular how to use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to your model.

Comment: I ultimately need the newly selected item in my action method that handles the update (which is called when the parent's form is submitted). So I figured I should be able to get the value either in the method inside the controller, or in the parent view somehow (and then pass it to the action method).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did try different ways. I added an Id for each "option", I then added Names for the options but couldnt get any of them to work. So I removed the reference altogether.

Comment: What is the signature of the POST method? (and you do not add `id` or `name` attributes to `<option>` elements. Its the `<select>` that needs a `name` attribute)

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditItems(Item viewItem)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Item i = dbContext.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == viewItem.Id);
                i.ItemId = viewItem.CategoryId;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return View("Competition", dbContext.Competitions);
            }

            return View(viewItem);
        }
The issue's that the Item that the view is sending the action is what was sent to view initially(old CategoryId) not the one selected by the user.

Comment: Put your code on your question, not on a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider rethinking the design and eliminating the use of partial view here.

You could use hidden input fields in the partial view and get them from javascript.

Ex: _PartialView.cshtml

```
<input type="hidden" id="someDataFromPartialSomehow" value="5" />
```

In your view

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var someDataFromPartialSomehow = $("#someDataFromPartialSomehow").val();
});
</script>
```

example from Haritha

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH @Douglas. Your idea did the trick. I created a new hidden field using the @Html.Hiddenfor("CategoryId). Then I called a javascript function "onchange" of my "select" element. The function simply set the value for CategoryId from the selected value from the list which worked like a charm. I appreciate your help again.